# Give AD Security Group Exchange Full Access Permission

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2007

My company is running Exchange 2007. From time to time, we need to open a user's Mailbox to to various tasks. Until now, we've been logging is as them and using Outlook directly. I'd like to give Full Access permission for all mailboxes to an "IT" security group in active directory, that way we can simply open their folders/mailbox in Outlook under our accounts. I understand the syntax to do this from PowerShell, but Exchange won't find the "IT" group name.

```
 Add-MailboxPermission -Identity 'IT' -User '*' -AccessRights 'FullAccess'
```

The command stalls on the Identity parameter. It works fine when another exchange user is specified, but not for AD groups. I CAN add the permission through the GUI, but only one account at a time. I've tried this in every configuration I could think of, including 'DOMAIN\IT' 'CN=IT,etc..', but no dice. Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I hope that the legalities have been addressed.

Comment: Have you tried the *full* distinguished name of the LDAP object?  (And, now that I think of it, wouldn't it be easier to just add the Organization Management role to your IT group?)

Comment: @mdpc Company email isn't private, that's policy.

Comment: @HopelessN00b The OM role only gives you rights to define permissions, such as grant yourself access, not the actual access itself, I think...could be wrong. My colleague has all the Exchange roles though, and he couldn't directly access other mailboxes. I will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: @tfrederick74656  Yeah, well I assumed OM had access to all the mailboxes...I guess that doesn't have to be the case, but it's the way I've always set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it backwards there. The `-user` reference is to the security principal that you *give permission* to. `-Identity` is the identity of the resource that the `-user` gets permissions on.

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited 
foreach($Mailbox in $Mailboxes){Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User 'IT' -AccessRights 'FullAccess'}
```

Comment: doh! I can't believe I missed that! I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning.